# Probabilistic (~50%) error on boot regarding "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock...missing codepage or helper program, or other error"

Tags: linux, boot, mount, nvme, superblock

I've found a ton of posts on the internet regarding this error:

`wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xxx,missing codepage or helper program, or other error`

Yet I have never found any case where the error just "sometimes" appears when booting.

Whenever I boot my linux machine I sometimes get the mentioned error and sometimes it just works fine. It's around a 50/50 chance and I have not been able to see a pattern in any way.

If I get the error, I just reboot and try again; I've been doing this for the past half a year. 3 boots is usually the maximum n. of times I have to boot till I get to my desktop.

If I try mounting the drive in the emergency shell, no error pops up whatsoever and I can write/read to/from the drive without any problem.

I would like to know if this is a fixable problem or if I should send back the nvme drive (it still has warranty).

```
Kernel: 6.2.8-alderlake-xanmod1-1 (Xanmod + GCC optimizations)  
OS: ArchLinux  
Drive: Kingston KC3000 PCIe 4.0, 1TB, bought separately from the laptop  
Laptop: Rog Zephyrus m16
```

EDIT:
I have two drives with windows/linux dual boot. Linux tries to boot /dev/nvme1n1p1, but I just found out that from the emergency shell I can only mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 which is actually the linux root that is supposed to be booted. Whenever I get to boot into the desktop, then an fdisk -l shows me that the linux drive is correctly labeled as nvme1n1p1, therefore I suppose that the system is only able to boot when the linux drive is assigned "nvme1" and the windows drive is assigned "nvme0". I've manually specified the kernel command line with EFISTUB as such:
`root=/dev/nvme1n1p1 resume=/dev/nvme1n1p2 rw quiet modprobe.blacklist=nouveau ibt=off initrd=\initramfs-linux-xanmod.img`

Comment: is this your boot drive?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it is, but I've just modified edited the question due to the fact that appartently nvme1 is the boot drive only some of the times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem: I told the kernel to boot "/dev/nvme1" instead of using labels or partition UUIDs; this caused a windows drive to be sometimes discovered as "nvme0" and sometimes "nvme1". Whenever the windows drive got "nvme1" (around 50% of the time) then the system couldn't boot it because of a fat-fs problem (fortunately I think).
I'm solving right now by using partition labels or UUIDs instead of paths, which was actually advised and now I know why.

It's amazing how asking a question online suddenly makes you find the solution; sorry for the fuzz.